# Knowing when there is ordering guarantee between 'constant' and 'dynamic' initialisation

Tags: c++, static

Let's just say I have a class:

```
struct StaticVector
{
    constexpr StaticVector() {  member = 7;};
    
    char member = 0;
};
 
inline constexpr StaticVector staticvector;
// Or 'constinit', this is a global namespace member.
```

`staticvector` is 'constant' initialized, which means the program just directly writes the bytes into the program.

Now in another translation unit:

```
#include "filecontainingstaticvector.h"
int alsoStaticObject = [](){ return rand() * staticvector.member; }();
// This should be 'dynamically initialized', which is guaranteed
// to come AFTER 'zero' and 'constant' initialisation
```

Because it's dynamic initialization even though it's in another compilation unit when this is initialised the member in `staticvector` will be `7` as assigned in its constructor, right? But:

```
#include "filecontainingstaticvector.h"
int alsoStaticObject = [](){ return staticvector.member; }();
```

Now it seems that the condition of whether `alsoStaticObject` is guaranteed to be initialized AFTER `staticvector` is whether the expression after `=` can be evaluated at compile-time, right? And whether or not you have any guarantee about their ordering is which objects fall into which categories of 'dynamic' or 'constant' initialization, right?

So if we wanted to know for sure we'd have to do something like:

```
#include "filecontainingstaticvector.h"
constexpr/constinit int alsoStaticObject = [](){ return staticvector.member; }();
```

And if it fails to compile then do we have that guarantee? Still, if it fails to compile, meaning the compiler wasn't able to evaluate it at compile-time do we have the guarantee that it falls into the 'dynamic' initialization category? If not we're guaranteed it falls into the 'constant' category? Is that a good method of testing?

Comment: Don't do that. <g>

Comment: @Ghasem - `initialisation` is not wrong. This is the way the Brits spell it, and they invented the language.

Comment: So you want to make sure that: the order of initialization is as expected, because otherwise constexpr would warn you?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, Sorry about that, and thanks for mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

`StaticVector staticvector;` is `constexpr`; its value is a compile time constant.  There is no before.  There is [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), at compile time, and after.

`constexpr` functions can fail to evaluate at compile time.  Variables cannot.

Now, compilers are free to do stupid stuff, like produce code that executes the initialization of `constexpr` variables at run time, but only *as if* they didn't.  This as if is limited by UB.